# CSS animation (appear from above, scale and dissapear) not working on iOS, Safari

Tags: css, ios, animation, mobile, frontend

I have a CSS animation that doesn't work on iOS devices.

I'm trying to animate an icon that will appear from above, scale and disappear.

I saw few more questions with the similar problem but nothing helped so ended up with the code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -25px, 0px);
    -webkit-opacity: 0.8;
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-opacity:1;
  }
  45% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  55%{ 
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
  }
  60%{ 
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear {
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-animation: appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear 1.5s linear;
  -moz-animation: appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear 1.5s linear;
  -ms-animation: appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear 1.5s linear;
  -o-animation: appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear 1.5s linear;
  animation: appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear 1.5s linear;
}
```

I also have the same keyframes just without -webkit-.

I've tried adding transform and opacity without -webkit- to the webkit keyframes but nothing...

Comment: **I've tried adding transform and opacity without -webkit- to the webkit keyframes but nothing...** doesn't make sense to use non-prefixed properties inside a `-webkit-`-keyframes animation.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti true... any ideas why its not working?

Comment: You would need to reproduce the issue in a code snippet here, it's hard to tell what could be causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

At least on IOS Safari there seems to be some problem with doing the translations when also changing the opacity.

I have no idea why, but putting in an otherwise redundant property setting seems to do the trick. In this snippet I put in a color: black but also found it worked OK putting in background: transparent.

```html
<style>
  @-webkit-keyframes appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
      -webkit-opacity: 0;
    }
    20% {
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -25px, 0px);
      color: black;
      /* this should make no difference but it seems to for IOS Safari at least */
      -webkit-opacity: 0.8;
    }
    30% {
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
      color: black;
      /* this should make no difference but it seems to for IOS Safari at least */
      -webkit-opacity: 1;
    }
    45% {
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2);
    }
    50% {
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    }
    55% {
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
    }
    60% {
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    100% {
      /* note that this translate3d has no effect as it's overridden by the next transform */
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  
  .appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear {
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-animation: appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear 1.5s linear;
    -moz-animation: appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear 1.5s linear;
    -ms-animation: appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear 1.5s linear;
    -o-animation: appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear 1.5s linear;
    animation: appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear 1.5s linear;
    /* added just for demo so we can see what is going on */
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
</style>
<div class="appearFromAboveAndScaleAndDissapear">abcde</div>
```

Note: there is a bug in your settings in that last 100% keyframe the first transform will be overridden by the second one. If you want both of them, put them on the same line.